# Python: return all linked list items

Tags: python

I've got some problem with returning values from the node, I've made:

```
class Node():
  def __init__(self, item, next = None):
    self.item = item
    self.next = next

class upp2():
  def __init__(self):
    self.top=None
    mening=input('Write a meaning: ')
    for ordet in mening.split():
      self.put(ordet)

  def put(self, newdata):
    node= Node(newdata, self.top)
    self.top=node

  def pop(self):
    while self.top.item != None:
      theitem = self.top.item
      self.top = self.top.next
      return theitem


upp=upp2()
print(upp.pop())
```

The code works as following: you write a meaning, the meaning is splited into separate words and stored in the node. The node part works, but I've got a problem returning all the words. The pop() returns just the last word, and the rest is untouched. What I mean is:

if I write a meaning: "My name is Ben" I want it to return:

```
'Ben
is
name
My'
```

but i only get Ben. Thank's in advance

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen the same question by a different user. The exact same question.

Comment: I couldn't find anything that worked for me

Comment: Why are you doing this, why not `"My name is Ben".split()[::-1]`

Comment: the task is to be able to write anything, make it a linked list and then terurn it all, so that node is empty

Comment: So this is a homework question? Because, what you're trying to achieve can be accomplished in a one liner.

Comment: Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong, but this strongly looks like homework and like a "Please debug my code"-Question, voting to close.

Comment: Well, to finish it: `'\n'.join("My name is Ben".split()[::-1])`

Comment: my question was how to return all the values in linked list, not to print out the words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 problems in your code.

First as noted by hyades, the return goes out of your loop and you should construct a generator with `yield`

Next, your test for ending the loop is wrong. It should be `while self.top != None:`

`upp2.pop` should become :

```
def pop(self):
    while self.top != None:
        theitem = self.top.item
        self.top = self.top.next
        yield theitem
```

And you could use it that way :

```
for x in upp.pop():
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is correct. But the `return` over there will break the `for` loop, resulting in only 1 value being returned to you.

So if your aim is printing the words, you may replace it with `print(theitem)` or use `yield(theitem)` if you want to use this elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution to follow as much as possible your code:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, item, n = None):
        self.item = item
        self.n = n

class upp2():
    def __init__(self):
        self.top=None
        mening=input('Write a meaning: ')
        for ordet in mening.split():
            self.put(ordet)
    def put(self, newdata):
        node = Node(newdata, self.top)
        self.top=node
    def pop(self):
        while self.top != None:
            theitem = self.top.item
            self.top = self.top.n
            if(theitem):
                print(theitem, end=' ') #for python 3.x
                #print theitem,         #for python 2.x

upp=upp2()
upp.pop()

#input: my name is user2149616
#output:user2149616 is name my
```

As first I would avoid to use next as it's a python keyword (into Node class definition). Secondly your main error is the return inside while. It stops the functions and therefore it will print just first node's content.
I hope this could help.
Regards